# Auto generation of POJO domain java classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

What is the best practice for generating entity class (Java code) , when ever model changes?
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

In the example application above,lets say there is a new field `movieDuration` in `Movie` entity. whats the best way to get this change into Movie.java. Hand-coding is definitely not an option for large projects.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Phaneendra

Comment: *Hand-coding is definitely not an option for large projects.* **why not?**

Comment: Not impossible but prone to errors. If there is a better way to do it, why not find it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say use APT to generate the code for you.  Though there may be one that exists for what you need such as https://projectlombok.org/ it isn't too difficult to create a code generator if you need it.

I've created a few as well you can use them for reference.

- https://github.com/trajano/jetng
- https://github.com/trajano/jpa-apt

The hardest part is getting the initial plumbing but once you got it it's just repeat

Comment: could you provide more details about APT. any links, examples.

Comment: lombok is for removing bolierplate. getters and setters etc.
My question is
about adding new fields to exiting class.

[some config having defining the class]->[Some automation]->[updated class]

Comment: Well as long as it is annotations you can make it replace the other class not sure about updating because updating would require you to parse the original.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano I am using neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver. When I use it alone with neo4j it works. But when I try to use spring-data-neo4j and spring-data-cassandra together either of it doesn't work. The annotations I used alone in neo4j and cassandra gets mixed in that. Kindly, can you give your insight in the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44033599/3035846 !