# How to configure neo4j and cassandra repositories in same spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-cassandra

I have configured neo4j and cassandra repositories separately with spring boot using spring-data. However, when I try to use two repositories in the same projects it doesn't work as expected.

This is my folder structure.

-----org.test.project

```
 -----controller
      BarController
      FooController
 -----models
      -----dao
           -----cassandra
                BarDAO
                FooDAO
           -----neo4j
                BarDAO
                FooDAO
 -----repositories
      -----cassandra
           BarRepository
           FooRepository
      -----neo
           BarRepository 
           FooRepository
 -----services
      CassandraService (Has cassandra repositories @Autowired)
      NeoService(Has neo repositories @Autowired)
 TestApp.java
```

Note that all the repositories extend respective spring-datarepository with respective DAO.

When I run with this configurations it gives the following error.

```
 Field airportRepository in org.test.project.TestApp required a bean of type 'org.test.project.repositories.cassandra.BarRepository' that could not be found.
```

I tried changing the Repository names. Then it started to work.

**First question is can't we have same names as they are in different packages and start working**

Though it started to work this time it gave an error in the authentication header.

```
 org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequestException: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit: No authentication header supplied.
```

I have already added ogm.properties, the same way I did when I was using neo4j repositories only. But it seems they no longer get applied. So I added following into application.properties.

```
 spring.data.neo4j.password=neo4j
 spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
```

**Second question is, how can I configure neo4j just as the same way I did only with neo4j? I have defined following in ogm.properties. How can I apply this into neo4j configurations?**

```
 #Driver, required
 driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver

 #URI of the Neo4j database, required. If no port is specified, the          
 #default port 7687 is used. Otherwise, a port can be specified with   
 #bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:1234

 URI=bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost

 #Connection pool size (the maximum number of sessions per URL),    
 #optional, defaults to 50

 connection.pool.size=150

 #Encryption level (TLS), optional, defaults to REQUIRED. Valid  
 #values are NONE,REQUIRED

 encryption.level=NONE
```

With the above changes, now it is giving following error.

```
 org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: No identity field found for class: org.rozzie.processor.models.dao.cassandra.FlightDAO
```

Note that a neo4j.ogm exception is thrown for the cassandra models. What is happening under the hood. **How can I configure these two databases with spring boot in one project as above?**

Comment: Can you show your java configuration? The one where you have `@EnableXRepositories` and ogm's `SessionFactory` etc..

Comment: @frant.hartm I am new to Spring. I didn't have specific Java configuration file when I experimented spring-data-neo4j and spring-data-cassandra separately. Full code (as I have explained in the start) is at https://github.com/ChamaraPhilipsuom/rozzie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the Spring Boot autoconfiguration is not able to handle multiple Spring Data projects at the same time.

Please refer to documentation for [Spring Data Neo4j](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference.getting_started.spring-configuration) and [Spring Data Cassandra](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.cassandra-java-config)

In particular you should point SDN module to neo4j repositories only

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.test.project.repositories.neo")
```

and similarly for cassandra.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. This exactly is the issue behind the problem. Where should I add the configuration class in the hierarchy? I am still a newbie to java spring. So appreciate your help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

I have used neo4j with mongo. I don't see any issues. I presume it should be same with cassandra. This is all the configuration I have

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.in.neo4j.repository.neo")
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.in.neo4j.repository.mongo")
public class Neo4JApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Neo4JApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And in my properties file I have

```
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j  
spring.data.neo4j.password=admin  

spring.data.mongodb.database=blah  
spring.data.mongodb.host=blahblah  
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```